# responsive image background size cover

Tags: css, html, responsive

I am trying to use an image as background as cover. But the image shows different in different window size. I tried to see on developer tool on chrome. On my image there have curve shape, and its totally looks different for larger screen as well as mobile device.

I want to show the image in same looks for all of the window size. Here is my css code.

```
background-image:url(../wp-content/uploads/2018/06/footer-wave-img.png);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover ;
height:auto;
```

Please give me any idea what I have to do.

Comment: It's hard to answer this without image as I just assume what you want, but have you tried centering the background image?

Comment: With different, you mean like zoomed in, zoomed out? Please provide more info or provide a jsfiddle

Comment: here is my url: http://staging.accessar.co/, please check the background image for "Innovative minds" text, just before footer

Comment: I didn't do any zoomed in, zoomed out. I checked them on chrome browser, developer tools option.

Answer (score 1):

For several sites I've built this has been what I've use for a **responsive** large `background-image`

```
    img   {   
        height: auto; 
        width: 100%;
        background-image: url(../wp-content/uploads/2018/06/footer-wave-img.png);
        background-position: 0%, 0%, 50%, 50%;
        background-size: auto, cover;
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the background-size property to `"100% 100%"`, this will allow the background to be independent of the resolution of the device. However, the background image will stretch to cover the entire content area of your element.
Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wxhek2pL/18/) for that.
In case, you wish to keep the proportions of the image same, you can try `background-size: 100%;` this alone too.